# How to version Docker images on Jenkins and pass it to the Kubernetes YAML files

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, yaml, jenkins-pipeline

Basically I'm trying to create a pipeline on my local Jenkins, create an image and then send to Docker Hub. Then I'll deploy this image on our local Kubernetes(Server IP:10.10.10.4).

So Jenkins pipeline script is below;

```
docker build -t test123/demo:$BUILD_NUMBER . 
docker login --username=testuser --password=testpass
docker push test123/demo:$BUILD_NUMBER
ssh -tt root@10.10.10.4 'kubectl apply -f hybris-deployment.yaml'
```

So the problem is; I can tag succesfully images with $BUILD_NUMBER and push to Docker hub. Then I have to use this $BUILD_NUMBER in the Kubernetes server's YAML file and deploy it.

But I can't pass this $BUILD_NUMBER to the Kubernetes server. Somehow I should send this build number with the ssh command and use it in the YAML file as a tag.

Any idea how can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you create your pipeline something like

if you **deployment.yaml** file is like

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-image
  labels:
    app: test-image
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-image
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-image
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: TEST_IMAGE_NAME
        name: test-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        - containerPort: 443
          name: https
```

in pipeline, you can change the image and replace this part in **deployment.yaml**

```
sed -i "s,TEST_IMAGE_NAME,gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA," deployment.yaml
```

so this command will replace line, in **deployment.yaml** and this way image URL updated and you can apply the YAML file.

you can see the example jenkin file here : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/continuous-deployment-on-kubernetes/blob/master/sample-app/Jenkinsfile

whole project link : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/continuous-deployment-on-kubernetes

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. For example first pipeline command should be like this? "" docker build -t test123/"sed -i "s,TEST_IMAGE_NAME,gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA," .

Comment: @yatta check for this : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/continuous-deployment-on-kubernetes/blob/master/sample-app/Jenkinsfile do let me still you have any issue.